# can't interact with UIScrollView after setContentOffset

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

In my app I have a small area I can drag my finger on and move accordingly a much bigger `UIScrollView`. The `UIScrollView` has a lot of buttons inside.

-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-

ScrollView

----Container

--------Button

--------Button

--------Button

This works great and the `UIScrollView` moves the way it should, the problem is that after I finish dragging the `UIScrollView` becomes unresponsive to taps. If i'll tap the buttons on it nothing will happen. If I'll do a little slide on the actual `UIScrollView` it will reset to its original location and will become responsive to taps again.

I'm pretty sure it's the container fault (removing it and adding the button to the `UIScrollView` works great) but I need to have zooming capabilities and adding a container to a scrollview is the only way I know.

```
- (void)draging:(UIControl *)c withEvent:ev {
    UITouch *touch = [[ev allTouches] anyObject];
    currentTouchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"Draging x : %f y : %f", currentTouchPoint.x, currentTouchPoint.y);
   [_myScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(currentTouchPoint.x*4, currentTouchPoint.y*2) animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up subclassing UIScrollView and used this:

```
#import "scrollViewWithButtons.h"

@implementation scrollViewWithButtons

- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view
{
    return ![view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]];
}

@end
```